# Two geojson files not superposing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, geojson

I'm facing a problem trying to superpose two geojson files ( look [Mapshaper's view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBu2k.png) ).
The two geojson files should superpose as they both have coordinates of switzerland..

And how can I show the 2 geojson files with d3 ? Do I need to merge them first or is there another way ?

Thanks for your time, I am really lost, not used to d3 and neither to geojson ^^

Here are the beginning of my files, they are really long so I can't put all of the content :

First one :

> {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID_0":223,"ISO":"CHE","NAME_0":"Switzerland","ID_1":1,"NAME_1":"Aargau","HASC_1":"CH.AG","CCN_1":0,"CCA_1":null,"TYPE_1":"Canton|Kanton|Chantun","ENGTYPE_1":"Canton","NL_NAME_1":null,"VARNAME_1":"Argovia|Arg¢via|Argovie"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[8.226543426513786,47.605094909668026],[8.226647377014274,47.60506820678722],[8.227575302123967,47.60508728027344],[8.228583335876465,47.60519409179699]

And the other one :

> {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
>   {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[8.7002707,47.5135459],[8.6988295,47.5144807],[8.699325,47.5147123],[8.7005701,47.5137642],[8.7002707,47.5135459]]]},"properties":{"landuse":"orchard","id":"way/22964818"},"id":"way/22964818"},
>   {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[9.1022943,47.449044],[9.1033691,47.4489294],[9.1033495,47.44933],[9.1037247,47.4493119],[9.1035645,47.4487965],[9.1031659,47.4488474],[9.1010074,47.4487085],[9.1007319,47.4493472],[9.1023123,47.4493841],[9.1022943,47.449044]]]},"properties":{"landuse":"orchard","id":"way/33455449"},"id":"way/33455449"},

It should be switzerland's cantons map and the apples orchards in switzerland too.

Comment: If you include your geojson files, or at least sections of them (starting with the beginning of each file) we can better help. With only an image it isn't possible to say for certain what is happening).

Comment: I added the beginning of the files, they are too big to put everything here ! But you are right I should have included them from the beginning. Is it possible that the geojson files already passed a transformation step ?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Is there any metadata associated with the geojson layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the available information it appears your dataset includes information outside of Switzerland.

Using the coordinates contained in the geojson, we can rule out the potential problem of using differently projected coordinate systems. It appears as though both use unprojected data (as D3 geoProjections require) given the range of values in the short sections of code above.

Further, the area shown is around Lake Constance, and the distances of orchard features from Switzerland are too great to be an issue of datum shift.

Also, the coordinates provided in each layer appear to line up with features in WGS84 - the orchard feature you show in the geojson snippet appears to roughly align with an actual orchard, so it is unlikely that there is a problem with your coordinates.

This leaves us with the simplest of potential problems: your dataset includes data from nearby border regions. I rubbersheeted your image over a map of Switzerland (coarsely based on the image), and would say that a 15 km buffer was applied to Switzerland when classifying land uses.

This assumption is supported by the gap of orchards where Lake Constance should be and the likely presence of orchards (based on a cursory look at imagery, aided by the rough rubbersheeting) on the German side of Lake Constance. It is also not uncommon for datasets to spill over borders, especially when image classification is used, as imagery rarely conforms to borders.

If orchards outside of Switzerland are a problem, you can use a number of programs to clip features (including mapshaper.org - see console commands) so that only features inside Switzerland remain.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was possible but with the data I have I feel like most of it is outside and that's why it seemed strange.